# Register All Classes Manually or there is an automatic way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. I am new to AutoFac. I have lot of classes and for each class I have to do,

```
builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationService>().As<IAuthenticationService>();
builder.RegisterType<IAuthenticationRepositry>().As<AuthenticationRepositry>();
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
```

Registering each type is time-consuming and quite easily forget-able. Is there is any automatic way to register components in AutoFac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to automatically register all types *as their interfaces*, you can use `RegisterAssemblyTypes`:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Or `AsSelf`, if you want to resolve concrete implementations.

Comment: Is AsImplementedInterfaces convention is to map IX to X?

Comment: @user960567 Nope, there's no convention. It just registers the classes as the interfaces they implement. Then, when you're resolving the interface, you'll get the class that was registered. I'm not entirely sure how it works when there are e.g. two implementations of the same interface. But then, you can probably override those settings manually while getting 90% of all other interfaces set up by registering assembly types.

Answer (score 1):

Your XXXService and XXXRepository classes will likely violate the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles (such as SRP, OCP, and ISP). Try hiding business logic and repository logic behind generic abstractions as can be learned [here](https://bit.ly/1govtpG) and [here](https://bit.ly/1dpeBdl). This makes it easy to add cross-cutting concerns to these classes and allows you to register each group in a single line of code:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))));

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<>))));

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRepository<>))));
```

Comment: What does IsClosedTypeOf method means?

Comment: @user960567: That is an helper (extension) method of Autofac that allows to check whether the given type `a` is a closed version of the supplied open generic type. `ICommandHandler<>` is the open generic type, while `ICommandHandler<MyCommand>` is a closed generic version of that type.

Comment: Thanks. I will your posts but I think it's very hard to read. I am trying.